# leaflet clustering by state in r coding, as well as adding dates together from two different columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet, axis-labels

I thank anyone in advance greatly for any help provided.

I am trying to organize the output of my leaflet map by clustering my markers. I am new to leaflet and the cluster function, and I am wondering if there is a way to cluster my markers by state instead of the default clustering.

Any other tips that could help my map of wildfires be more presentable would be welcome. I am trying to highlight west coast wildfires, to include Arizona, Nevada, Utah, and Texas. Also, maybe in a second map I can show that the wildfires on the west coast last longer by the dates listed in my data file. I'm working on an easier way to count those dates in R, but not sure how to do that either. The columns of those dates I would be using are disc_date_pre and cont_clean_date. It might also be cool to show a leaflet by size of the fire.

My data frame is called wildfires
and my subset for my westcoast fires is below

```
westcoastwildfires <- subset(wildfires, state %in% c("CA","TX","OR","WA","AK","NV","AZ","UT"))
```

I also tried to plot a ggplot for the westcoast fires by start and end date, but I am not sure how to fix my axis labels to actually show the dates more clearly, and I can only assume that ggplot is not putting the dates in order by year, but in order by month, putting the dates all out of order.

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_point(data=westcoastwildfires, 
                   aes(x=disc_date_pre, y=cont_clean_date, fill = state), 
                   shape=21, 
                   alpha = 0.8,
                   size = 9, 
                   color = "black") +
    theme_light(base_size=20) 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold",color= "#ce6600", hjust = 0.5, size = 50),
          plot.subtitle=element_text(color="#8f673f", hjust = 0.5, size = 30), 
          plot.caption=element_text(color="grey50", size = 30),
          axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 35, face = "bold", color = "#8f673f"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 35, face = "bold", color = "#8f673f"))+
    ggtitle("How long Fires lasted by State") + 
    labs(x="Start Date",
         y="End Date")
```

My leaflet code so far is pretty basic

```
leaflet(wildfires) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

data below

```
dput(head(wildfires))


structure(list(X = 0:5, Unnamed..0 = 0:5, fire_name = c("", "", 
"", "WNA  1", "", ""), fire_size = c(10, 3, 60, 1, 2, 1), fire_size_class = c("C", 
"B", "C", "B", "B", "B"), stat_cause_descr = c("Missing/Undefined", 
"Arson", "Arson", "Debris Burning", "Miscellaneous", "Debris Burning"
), latitude = c(18.105072, 35.03832998, 34.9478, 39.6414, 30.7006, 
32.0639), longitude = c(-66.753044, -87.60999999, -88.7225, -119.3083, 
-90.5914, -82.4178), state = c("PR", "TN", "MS", "NV", "LA", 
"GA"), disc_clean_date = c("2/11/2007", "12/11/2006", "2/29/2004", 
"6/6/2005", "9/22/1999", "3/22/1999"), cont_clean_date = c("", 
"", "", "6/6/2005", "", ""), discovery_month = c("Feb", "Dec", 
"Feb", "Jun", "Sep", "Mar"), disc_date_final = c("", "", "", 
"6/6/2005 2:14", "", ""), cont_date_final = c("", "", "", "6/6/2005 18:00", 
"", ""), putout_time = c("", "", "", "0 days 00:00:00.000000000", 
"", ""), disc_date_pre = c("1/12/2007", "11/11/2006", "1/30/2004", 
"5/7/2005", "8/23/1999", "2/20/1999"), disc_pre_year = c(2007L, 
2006L, 2004L, 2005L, 1999L, 1999L), disc_pre_month = c("Jan", 
"Nov", "Jan", "May", "Aug", "Feb"), wstation_usaf = c("785140", 
"723235", "723235", "724880", "722312", "722691"), dstation_m = c(58917.69716, 
32665.34327, 105122.1495, 43433.32978, 25940.57409, 53847.19792
), wstation_wban = c(11603L, 13896L, 13896L, 23185L, 3908L, 366L
), wstation_byear = c(1945L, 1978L, 1978L, 1942L, 1987L, 1942L
), wstation_eyear = c(2018L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2016L, 2020L
), Vegetation = c(12L, 15L, 16L, 0L, 12L, 12L), fire_mag = c(1, 
0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), weather_file = c("785140-11603-2007.gz", 
"723235-13896-2006.gz", "723235-13896-2004.gz", "724880-23185-2005.gz", 
"File Not Found", "File Not Found"), Temp_pre_30 = c(24.48097412, 
7.553433476, 4.971929825, 16.27596717, -1, -1), Temp_pre_15 = c(24.71692308, 
7.01, 5.782765957, 18.99618138, -1, -1), Temp_pre_7 = c(24.9025974, 
0.343529412, 5.55875, 18.1425641, -1, -1), Temp_cont = c(24.52796053, 
10.4482976, 13.69660023, 0, -1, -1), Wind_pre_30 = c(4.341807044, 
2.709763948, 3.364499484, 4.054982415, -1, -1), Wind_pre_15 = c(3.492857143, 
2.881707317, 2.923829787, 3.398329356, -1, -1), Wind_pre_7 = c(3.262091503, 
1.976470588, 2.695833333, 3.671282051, -1, -1), Wind_cont = c(3.250413223, 
2.122320303, 3.36905041, 0, -1, -1), Hum_pre_30 = c(78.21658986, 
70.84, 75.53162853, 44.77842907, -1, -1), Hum_pre_15 = c(76.79375, 
65.85891089, 75.86861314, 37.14081146, -1, -1), Hum_pre_7 = c(76.38157895, 
55.50588235, 76.81283422, 35.35384615, -1, -1), Hum_cont = c(78.72436975, 
81.68267831, 65.06380028, 0, -1, -1), Prec_pre_30 = c(0, 59.8, 
168.8, 10.4, -1, -1), Prec_pre_15 = c(0, 8.4, 42.2, 7.2, -1, 
-1), Prec_pre_7 = c(0, 0, 18.1, 0, -1, -1), Prec_cont = c(0, 
86.8, 124.5, 0, -1, -1), remoteness = c(0.0179233876865947, 0.184354951858787, 
0.194543513472489, 0.487447454850636, 0.214632944949511, 0.1396431681011
), condition = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
dput(head(westcoastwildfires))


structure(list(X = c(3L, 7L, 21L, 33L, 40L, 44L), Unnamed..0 = c(3L, 
7L, 21L, 33L, 40L, 44L), fire_name = c("WNA  1", "", "TELEPHONE FIRE", 
"CR 42600", "MARBLE HEAD", ""), fire_size = c(1, 1, 5, 2, 5, 
20), fire_size_class = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"), stat_cause_descr = c("Debris Burning", 
"Campfire", "Debris Burning", "Debris Burning", "Lightning", 
"Debris Burning"), latitude = c(39.6414, 30.90472001, 33.779575, 
33.669209, 40.8347, 32.56499998), longitude = c(-119.3083, -93.55749999, 
-96.025915, -95.490213, -112.8064, -96.1751), state = c("NV", 
"TX", "TX", "TX", "UT", "TX"), disc_clean_date = c("6/6/2005", 
"11/12/2005", "12/18/2010", "9/6/2011", "8/14/2006", "9/21/2005"
), cont_clean_date = c("6/6/2005", "", "", "", "8/15/2006", ""
), discovery_month = c("Jun", "Nov", "Dec", "Sep", "Aug", "Sep"
), disc_date_final = c("6/6/2005 2:14", "", "", "", "8/14/2006 21:30", 
""), cont_date_final = c("6/6/2005 18:00", "", "", "", "8/15/2006 14:30", 
""), putout_time = c("0 days 00:00:00.000000000", "", "", "", 
"1 days 00:00:00.000000000", ""), disc_date_pre = c("5/7/2005", 
"10/13/2005", "11/18/2010", "8/7/2011", "7/15/2006", "8/22/2005"
), disc_pre_year = c(2005L, 2005L, 2010L, 2011L, 2006L, 2005L
), disc_pre_month = c("May", "Oct", "Nov", "Aug", "Jul", "Aug"
), wstation_usaf = c("724880", "722820", "742513", "722587", 
"A00028", "722489"), dstation_m = c(43433.32978, 64017.11754, 
38613.8717, 5481.227824, 72772.05084, 18934.02673), wstation_wban = c(23185L, 
99999L, 99999L, 93955L, 4116L, 99999L), wstation_byear = c(1942L, 
1984L, 2006L, 2006L, 2004L, 1942L), wstation_eyear = c(2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L), Vegetation = c(0L, 12L, 16L, 
16L, 15L, 12L), fire_mag = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1), weather_file = c("724880-23185-2005.gz", 
"722820-99999-2005.gz", "742513-53937-2010.gz", "722587-93955-2011.gz", 
"File Not Found", "722489-99999-2005.gz"), Temp_pre_30 = c(16.27596717, 
16.8519389, 9.156936011, 31.0192783, -1, 28.1309371), Temp_pre_15 = c(18.99618138, 
16.99778271, 6.582005623, 30.14500942, -1, 27.08040201), Temp_pre_7 = c(18.1425641, 
20.43478261, 6.558044807, 29.62350598, -1, 27.21354167), Temp_cont = c(0, 
11.98555957, 7.834, 23.27791321, -1, 23.61437908), Wind_pre_30 = c(4.054982415, 
1.331257344, 4.251751518, 3.81606525, -1, 2.772785623), Wind_pre_15 = c(3.398329356, 
1.472949002, 4.165323336, 4.079190207, -1, 3.123869347), Wind_pre_7 = c(3.671282051, 
1.424782609, 5.025050916, 4.968924303, -1, 3.3390625), Wind_cont = c(0, 
2.148856799, 4.4614, 3.674487805, -1, 3.22496732), Hum_pre_30 = c(44.77842907, 
72.89947781, 62.30432645, 50.60751359, -1, 58.74293059), Hum_pre_15 = c(37.14081146, 
75.06138107, 60.11688312, 51.31638418, -1, 61.82871537), Hum_pre_7 = c(35.35384615, 
77.92462312, 53.78222222, 45.21912351, -1, 67.11518325), Hum_cont = c(0, 
70.73291139, 70.16266376, 46.01573255, -1, 61.75294118), Prec_pre_30 = c(10.4, 
28.4, 0, 1.8, -1, 38.6), Prec_pre_15 = c(7.2, 27.5, 0, 1.8, -1, 
32), Prec_pre_7 = c(0, 1.2, 0, 1.5, -1, 29), Prec_cont = c(0, 
55.4, 0, 9.2, -1, 26.5), remoteness = c(0.487447454850636, 0.241893505493523, 
0.262885025936781, 0.257938123566078, 0.421384117167764, 0.265119968041828
), condition = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(4L, 
8L, 22L, 34L, 41L, 45L), class = "data.frame")
```

As far as adding the dates together, I looked that up on stack and found a different answer and tried a few of the suggestions, but I wasn't sure how to get it to work for my data set.

Below are some of the examples I found and tried by plugging in my datat. I think I am just plugging my own data in incorrectly. I guess I'm just not sure how to do it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dates)[ ,.(Date = seq(Start, End, by = "day")), 
               by = 1:nrow(dates)][,
                                    .(count = .N), by = Date]
```

```
stack(table(do.call(c, Map(seq, dates$Start, dates$End, by = "1 day"))))
```

Comment: As is your question lacks the necessary focus: Instead of wrangling multiple and different questions and issues in one post please ask separate questions, i.e. one for the ggplot2 issue, one for the leaflet issue and one for the issue with "adding" your dates.

Comment: To fix your ggplot2 issue I would suggest to convert your dates to proper dates using `as.Date`, e.g. `westcoastwildfires$disc_date_pre <- as.Date(westcoastwildfires$disc_date_pre, format="%m/%d/%Y")`. Otherwise ggplot2 will order your dates alphabetically. Note however that your `cont_clean_date` contains missings so you have to deal with that.